# Create docker volumes in a different folder than /var/lib/docker/volume

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

By default `docker volume create` creates data volumes in `/var/lib/docker/volumes`. Is it possible to somehow specify a different path? My machine has a small SSD where `/var/lib/docker` lives on but I'd like the data volume to be on the slow but high-capacity hard drive.

I'm assuming I can first create a symlink in that folder and than create the volume but I was wondering if there was a proper way? perhaps through `docker-compose`?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Driver-specific options](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_create/#driver-specific-options) for `docker volume create`

> The built-in local driver on Linux accepts options similar to the
>   linux mount command.